# SwiftUI viewModel with array of [any PROTOCOL] inside

Tags: arrays, swiftui, view, observable, protocols

I am trying to implement viewModel which contains an array with observable objects and everything is covered by interfaces. How can I achieve this? My code right now gives an error

> Type 'any IItemViewModel' cannot conform to 'IItemViewModel'

```
protocol IItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var title: String { get }
}

final class ItemViewModel: IItemViewModel, ObservableObject {
    let title: String
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

protocol IMainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var list: [any IItemViewModel] { get }
}

final class MainViewModel: IMainViewModel {
    @Published var list = [any IItemViewModel]()
    
    required init() {
        list.append(ItemViewModel(title: "test1"))
    }
}

struct MainView<ViewModel>: View where ViewModel: MainViewModel  {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var items = [any IItemViewModel]()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(viewModel.list, id: \.title) { model in
                    ItemView(viewModel: model) // <-- ERROR HERE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView<ViewModel>: View where ViewModel: IItemViewModel {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Protocols don’t conform to the items they require. SwiftUI requires concrete types.

Comment: Yes, but how to solve this? We are looking on SwiftUI to implement new features to our existing UIKit app, but we want also save current flexibility level and cover everything by protocols.

Comment: You will have to cast it to a concrete type. You can’t use existential.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the `View` protocol for your view model, e.g. for read only:

```
struct MainView: View  {
    let items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
```

or for read/write:

```
struct MainView: View  {
    @State var items: [Item] = []

    var body: some View {
```

or

```
struct MainView: View  {
    @Binding var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
```

Comment: Why did you post that? I believe it's answer for another question. View protocol is designed for views, it shouldn't be adopted by ViewModels.

Comment: in SwiftUI the View protocol is a view model